# SVG elements that worked in past versions of iPython notebook dont seem to work any more

Tags: jupyter-notebook

A markdown cell with the following snippet would work correctly in earlier versions (I wish I had kept track of all the version numbers). I opened an old notebook recently and this no longer seems to work. Any suggestions on what is possibly wrong?

Here is the stylized relevant extract: If I put this is in a markdown cell, I am hoping to get a rectangle embedded in the text.

```
I want to draw a rectangle

<svg width="400" height="150" >
<g id="fig1">
    <text x="150" y="10" font-family="Verdana" font-size="10" fill="blue" > width </text>
    <rect x="50" y="20" width="100" height="50" style="fill:rgb(255,255,0);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
    <text x="2" y="65" font-family="Verdana" font-size="10" fill="blue" > height </text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: I guess the SVG display object is not option?

Comment: @Jacob I think I could find other ways of getting a similar result. As you suggest there are more ways to skin this cat. But before I put in the effort to go fix this in multiple places, just wanted to just make sure that I had not overlooked some simple recipe.